# Use sonarqube for visual studio project

Tags: .net, sonarqube

I am trying to use sonarqube with my mvc.net project. but my biggest confusion is that, how to provide project to sonarqube for testing? how could I able to do code analysis using it?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at our documentation site, which explains the necessary steps: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild

Basically, you'll need to have a SonarQube server running with the C#, JS, ... plugins. Then you can run the Scanner for MsBuild "begin" step to pull down settings from the SQ server, build your project with MsBuild, and then execute the Scanner for MsBuild "end" step to upload results to the SQ server.